# Pulling Tweets into a Spotify app

Tags: spotify

I'm building a little Spotify app that displays tweets from the current Artist playing. I'm using Bocoup's jQuery Twitter plugin to grab and display the tweets: http://code.bocoup.com/jquery-twitter-plugin/

MANIFEST.JSON

```
{
    "BundleType": "Application",
    "AppIcon": {
        "18x18": "tutorial.png"
    },
    "AppName": {
        "en": "News"
    },
    "SupportedLanguages": [
        "en"
    ],
    "RequiredPermissions": [
                "http://twitter.com"
                "http://*.twitter.com"
                "http://*.twimg.com"
    ],
    "VendorIdentifier": "com.News",
    "RequiredInterface": "1",
    "BundleVersion": "0.2",
    "BundleIdentifier": "News",
    "AppName": "News",
    "AppDescription": "Twitter updates from the Artist playing."
}
```

From the Index file:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#tweets').twitter({from: 'mediatemple', replies: false})
      launch();
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="info">
</div>
<div id="news">
</div>
<div id="tweets">
</div>
</body>
```

Nothing displays in Spotify when I open my app, but if I open the index.html file in a browser, the tweets appear. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RequiredPermissions JSON needs commas.

try:

```
"RequiredPermissions": [
            "http://twitter.com",
            "http://*.twitter.com",
            "http://*.twimg.com"
],
```

Things fail silently if there is a problem in the manifest. Always use a JSON linter (http://jsonlint.com/) to verify at least the format is proper JSON.

UPDATE: After any changes to manifest.json you must restart Spotify.

Comment: Thanks! I updated this, ran it through the linter and it was still not displaying. Then I restarted Spotify and it worked!

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on restarting Spotify after making changes in manifest.json